# What does the HBase MILLIS_BETWEEN_NEXTS counter represent?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I am running a map reduce job reading from HBase. There are some mappers that are much slower than others and the only significant difference in their counters is MILLIS_BETWEEN_NEXTS. I tried looking for an explanation of the metric but did not find anything. Do you know what this metric represents and how could it be optimzied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java doc says,

> sum of milliseconds between sequential next calls

It's pretty much what it says. You could see the `next()` method in the `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner` for the implementation details.

Reference :
http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/hbase/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/metrics/ScanMetrics.html#sumOfMillisSecBetweenNexts

Hope it helps.